# Trying to get current cell value of gridview in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
sqlqrystrng = "UPDATE temp_zone set zone_id = @zoneid, zone_name = @zonename WHERE auto_id = @autoid"
Dim strautoid As String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text()
End Sub
```

but strautoid always contains "" .....What to do

### html of gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" "AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">   
     <RowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" ForeColor="#333333" />
     <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Auto Id">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("auto_id") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zone Id">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("zone_id") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="grdtxt_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("zone_id") %>'>
               </asp:TextBox>
          </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edition" ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="False" />
       <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Deletion" ShowDeleteButton="True" CausesValidation="False" />
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Are you getting value from a label?

Comment: put the structure of your gridview

Comment: Nopes...... i m solving this from the past day but unable to solve it

Comment: Put the gridview code

Comment: HRML or vb.net... and i m new for this site my code is too long unable to fit in the text box

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="text-align: center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"><RowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" ForeColor="#333333" /><Columns><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Auto Id"><ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("auto_id") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zone Id"><ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("zone_id") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="grdtxt_id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("zone_id") %>'></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField><asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edition" ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="False" />
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Deletion" ShowDeleteButton="True" 
CausesValidation="False" /></Columns><AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" /></asp:GridView>

Comment: This is HTML code of gridview and now sending the row_updating event code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked this exactly, but you need something like:

```
Dim lblCell as label = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("labelID")
Dim strautoid As String = lblCell.Text
```

As i say, haven't checked exactly but the key to getting this correct is in the FindControl method, i hope that helps.

Comment: @5uperdan- It displays error like---------- object reference not set to an instance of an object in the second line of the code

Comment: @VPartapSinghSalathia That means that the findControl method isn't finding your control. Have you replaced "labelID" with "Label1" or "Label2" depending on which label it is that you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
You Have to Try this 

Dim strautoid As String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text()  instead of this ,try below

 TableCell cl = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];

(Label) lbl=(Label).cl.FindControl("Your Label ID");

Dim strautoid As String=lbl.Text;
```